# Android ListView is cutting off the ends of Strings in list when scrolling

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I wrote a ListView using some sample code from different places, and although the dynamic setting of the Adapter is working, for some reason, when I scroll to a different position, the ends of the strings in the list will magically dissappear. Why is this? The code for the adapter is this: Also, the list xml is just standard listview with no children. The children are added by this adapter.

```
package com.vrise.bellarmine;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private String[] gradesName;
    private String[] gradesVal;
    public EfficientAdapter(Context context, String[] gradesname, String[] gradesval) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        gradesName = gradesname;
        gradesVal = gradesval;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return gradesName.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
            holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.TextView02);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.text1.setText(gradesName[position]);
        holder.text2.setText(gradesVal[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text1;
        TextView text2;
    }
}
```

Also I for some reason can't add pics.
But what it looks like is: The list is scrolling, and when I scroll back up, what started out as "Calculus AB AP" is now "Calcu".

Comment: can you put here a screenshot of how it looks like, to show us what is the wrong behavior?

Comment: also show your list item xml, please